# Xen guest networking model

Tags: networking, xen

It's time to replace old server with new one. In old server all was setup on bare metal. With new server I try to set up virtual server for specific task.

Host OS is Debian 9. Guests I will run in HVM mode (also Debian). Planned servers are: MySql, email (postfix,curys,spam filters and all related to email), web server (nginx+php), web proxy (SSL terminator)

But question is about networking. I do not want that guests are visible from outside and they do not have public IP. But each guest must see other guests.

I created two bridges. `hostbr0` and `xenbr0`. In `hostbr0` I added physical interface `eno1` witch has one static IP (public). In `xenbr0` I added `vdum1` interface.

`vdum1` is virtual interface with `dummy` module, IP = 192.168.1.1. For all guests IP address is from 192.168.1.0 subnet. So all guests are in one network.

How I can configure iptables, so that guests have internet access? I am not asking for exact commands but for directions. Do I need to setup masquerading? Then witch interface must masquerade? Is it possible to set forwarding between bridges?

I already tried masquerading booth bridges and also interfaces but I cannot access internet from guest OS.

I also want to control guest access to internet. For example, mysql guest do not need internet at all (in general).

On host OS I will use `shorewall`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On host OS, you add a rule on IPTables which performs SNAT to the packets coming in from the internal guest and going outside.

In Shorewall, the entry looks like this in `/etc/shorewall/masq`:

```
eth0    192.168.10.1    10.10.10.10
```

Here, `eth0` is the interface connecting to the internet. `192.168.10.1` is the guest IP address you want to NAT. `10.10.10.10` is the IP address the packets will receive after SNAT (usually this is the same as host OS public IP address).

Comment: I will try it in this week and then report results.